# apache mod_auth_kerb binarys for win32

Tags: windows, apache, mod-auth-kerb

I wanna try to use Apache HTTP Server on Windows with mod_auth_kerb. But I faced to a problem that I cant find it. I tryed to google it but I can only see the discussion of the difficulties when trying to compile it.
Is subj exists? Where I can download something?